# ¿Cómo subrayar una palabra en un string al mostrarla en un JTextArea - JLabel?

Tags: java, java-swing, java-8

Es sencillo, tengo un string y hay algunas letras que me gustaría subrayar o poner en negritas.
Lo estoy haciendo en un JFrame, y mostrando la cadena en un JTextArea (También puede ser en un JLabel).

Tengo entendido que hay algunas etiquetas HTML para poder dar formato al texto, pero como la puedo aplicar aquí?

Este es mi código por ahora:

```
txtArea.setText("<strong>"+"Hola que tal, aquí va el subrayado"+"<strong>");
```

Comment: JTextArea hasta donde sé no soporta formato, por que no usas el JEditorPane?

Comment: Listo, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con un JTextArea me parece que no es posible, pero si puedes lograrlo con un JTextPane modificando la propiedad [contentType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JEditorPane.html#setContentType(java.lang.String)) ya que por default es `text/plain` y debes cambiarlo a `text/html`.

De la siguiente forma:

```
myJTextPanel.setContentType("text/html");
myJTextPanel.setText("<strong>Texto en negrilla</strong>");
```

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy bien, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Al usar un `JTextArea` no existe constante para cambiar a "underline" tu texto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso de un `JLabel` si lo puedes realizar definiendo el atributo `TextAttribute.UNDERLINE`

Ejemplo:

```
       JLabel label = new JLabel("Improve app performance with Kotlin coroutines");
        Font font =  new Font("Segoe Script", Font.BOLD, 20);
        Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
        attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
        label.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
        label.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        label.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,0));
```

Para tener como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfecto.

Comment: Excelente!, Saludos.